# Try in to verify println or Log in kotlin and android using mockk

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

Im trying to verify whether my code is printing in Kotlin or logging out the right Log in Android. With other function it is ok for me but for these kind of function can anyone show me how to do it.

```
    @Test
    fun mockTest() {
        println("hello")
        verify(exactly = 1){
            println("hello")
        }
    }
```

This is the error I have encountered.

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside verify { ... } block.

    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.checkMissingCalls(VerifyingState.kt:52)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.recordingDone(VerifyingState.kt:21)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.done(CommonCallRecorder.kt:48)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:60)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.VerifyBlockEvaluator.verify(VerifyBlockEvaluator.kt:27)
    at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalVerify(API.kt:118)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.verify(MockK.kt:139)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.verify$default(MockK.kt:136)
    at com.tictac.ExampleUnitTest.logExecutued(ExampleUnitTest.kt:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out on the website below that android is not recommend to mock that far.
However, you can still do it by adding this to the gradle build file.

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like `mockkStatic(Class.forName("kotlin.io.ConsoleKt")::class)`, but it's impossible

Even the print function used inside the mockk becomes a mockk, causing StackOverflow.

```
    @Test
    fun test() {
        mockkStatic(Class.forName("kotlin.io.ConsoleKt")::class)

        val log = "hello"

        every {
            println(log)
        } just Runs

        println(log)

        verify {
            println(log)
        }
    }
```

here is small sample

If possible, I would recommend not mockking that far.

Comment: I tried that but its keep telling me the same error I've encounter.